# ggplot x axis order days

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset currently sorted by date and time. I have a column called 'day' and is just the day of the month, in numerical form i.e. 1-31
I have a 14 days stretch that I want to plot, however it starts from 30th of one month, to the 13th of the next.
When I try to plot it, it orders 1-13,30,31.

How can I plot the x axis as it is found within the dataframe?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sample data with columns `day` and `value`.

```
df<-data.frame(day=c(30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),value=rnorm(10))
```

If column `day` contains just day values as numbers you can convert them to factor and set levels as original order of values.

```
ggplot(df,aes(factor(day,levels=df$day),value,group=1))+geom_line()
```